# How to get a property value of xml in Java .I am receivng a xml string and want a particular value

Tags: java, xml

I only want `app_id` of "Rahul2 test".

I am not storing this xml in file, how can I get it?

**Code:**

```
String s=resultWrapper.getAppBuilds();      
System.out.println(s);
```

**Output:**

```
<application app_name="Rahul1 Test" app_id="18" >
<customfield name="Custom 1" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 2" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 3" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 4" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 5" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 6" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 7" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 8" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 9" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 10" value=""/>
<build version>
</build>
</application>
<application app_name="Rahul2 Test" app_id="196" >
<customfield name="Custom 1" value=""/>
<customfield name="Custom 2" value=""/>
```

Answer (score 0):

convert the String to DOM xml ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/3906936/58082 ) and then use XPATH to get the property ( [How to get attribute value using XPath in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25259836) )